# Initialize array with function-depending size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, declaration, constexpr

I'm writing a programm to create a roster. Every month has a different number of shifts, which is determined by a function. At the beginning of the programm the user enters the month, the according number of shifts gets calculated in a function and then I want to create a 2-dimensional array with that size. But aparrently I can't initialize an array like this. Can anyone help me out?

As you may have noticed, I'm a very inexperienced beginner, so I apologise for not expressing myself perfectly in advance.

```
//function to calculate number of shifts
const int getShift(const int month, const int year) {
    ...
    return x;
}

int main(){
int array[getShift(8,2019)[2];
}
```

I got an error along the lines of "expression did not evaluate to a constant" although that number actually is a constant, or at least I want it to be one...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use malloc or calloc rather than array syntax.

Comment: @nicomp That is not a good suggestion in modern C++

Comment: A `std::vector` is most likely what you want.

Comment: @nicomp No, don't.

Comment: @nicomp "Use malloc or calloc" - In modern (or even ancient) C++, no please don't do that. Use `new` or (better) a `std::vector`. `malloc` and `calloc` don't call constructors - you almost *never* want to use them in C++.

Comment: malloc is just fine. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need an array with a dynamic size, almost always the best solution in C++ is to use a vector.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

//function to calculate number of shifts
int getShift(int month, int year) {
    ...
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> array(getShift(8,2019));
}
```

Since you need a 2D array, and since regular arrays can't be members of a vector, I've also used a `std::array<int, 2>` for the second dimension.

Now you can use `array` pretty much like a regular 2D array, in particular you can use `array[i][j]` to access individual elements of the 2D array.

Comment: Thank you, that did solve my problem in an elegant way. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

The function must to be declared with the specifier `constexpr` and accordingly to satisfy the requirements for `constexpr` functions..

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int getShift( int x, int y )
{
    return y / x;
}

int main()
{
    int array[getShift(8,2019)][2];

    std::cout << sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
252
```

Here is a list of requirements for the body of constexpr functions (C++20)

> (3.4) — its function-body shall not enclose (Clause 8)
>
> (3.4.1) — an asm-definition,
>
> (3.4.2) — a goto statement,
>
> (3.4.3) — an identifier label (8.1),
>
> (3.4.4) — a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static
>   or thread storage duration or for which no initialization is
>   performed.

Comment: downvote might come from old c++ users whose experience limited to c-like c++, I guess.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  `sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array )` - We have [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) for that these days.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes we have but not all users use modern compilers.:)

Comment: The OP says *At the beginning of the programm the user enters the monthAt the beginning of the programm the user enters the month*, it's clear that `getShift depends` on user input so a `constexpr` is impossible.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow True, but (IMHO) the answer should use/advocate the modern way and then, maybe, mention the old way in a footnote.  Or at least *mention* the modern way.

Comment: @john But in his example he is using constants.:)